# Query to extract a key -> value table to a columnar one

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table:

```
 itemid            itemkey        itemvalue    
 ----------------  -------------  ------------ 
 123               Colour         Red            
 123               Size           Medium             
 123               Fabric         Cotton
```

Is there a simple query **to obtain** something like this:

```
   itemid          Colour       Size        Fabric
   ----            ----         ---         ---
   123             Red          Medium      Cotton     
   124             Yellow       Large       Poly
   ...
```

### Edit

There is also a variant when the first table other than all the tags contains a date, and in your pivot you need to select the latest tag, e.g.:

```
 itemid            itemkey        itemvalue     date
 ----------------  -------------  ------------  ------
 123               Colour         Red            2017-03
 123               Colour         Yellow         2017-04
 123               Size           Medium             
 123               Fabric         Cotton
```

So now the for the record 123 the color should be **Yellow** and not red as its date is previous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called pivoting and should be done in application code if you have dynamic number of items.

If the items are known beforehand, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select itemid,
    max(case when itemkey = 'Colour' then itemvalue end) as Colour,
    max(case when itemkey = 'Size' then itemvalue end) as Size,
    max(case when itemkey = 'Fabric' then itemvalue end) as Fabric,
    . . . 
from your_table
group by itemid;
```

If you have versioning based on date, you can use subquery to find the latest record and then do the pivoting:

```
select  itemid,
    max(case when itemkey = 'Colour' then itemvalue end) as Colour,
    max(case when itemkey = 'Size' then itemvalue end) as Size,
    max(case when itemkey = 'Fabric' then itemvalue end) as Fabric,
    . . . 
from your_table t
join (
    select itemid, itemkey
        max(date) as date
    from your_table
    group by itemid, itemkey
    ) t2 using (itemid, itemkey, date)
group by itemid;
```

Comment: Thanks GurV +1! I have edited my question to include a slightly difficult query, e.g.: when each tag has a date and you need to extract only the latest, is there a simple way? Without going into the rabbit hole of the greatest-n-per-group questions?

Comment: @giò - Updated the answer.

Comment: That's impressive... that's also probabily the best way to solve the greatest-n-per-group kind of questions